# SwiftUI simple view, need a push into right direction

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am complete beginner with SwiftUI and I can't wrap my head around how to connect these images with  views that represents lines. Now I simply have 3 VStacks with image and text and put them into a HStack, but don't know how to connect these images with a line shown in red in the picture I attached. Note that there's some space between the line and the image. I need general direction and some hints, full working code not necessary.

Thank you.

[image: 3 boxes, arranged horizontally, with image inside. Below each box there is a Text. In between each box is red line.]

Answer (score 2):

How's this?

[image: 3 boxes with smiley inside and text below. Red line between boxes]

In SwiftUI, you use `HStack`s and `VStack`s to stack your Views. For the red line, a `Rectangle` should do. Here's the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack { /// horizontal stack
            
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "face.smiling")
                    .font(.system(size: 80))
                    .padding()
                    .border(Color.black, width: 5)
                    
                Text("Text TEXTEXT")
            }
            
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(height: 5)
            
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "face.smiling")
                    .font(.system(size: 80))
                    .padding()
                    .border(Color.black, width: 5)
                    
                Text("Text TEXTEXT")
            }
            
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(height: 5)
            
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "face.smiling")
                    .font(.system(size: 80))
                    .padding()
                    .border(Color.black, width: 5)
                    
                Text("Text TEXTEXT")
            }
            
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .previewLayout(.fixed(width: 800, height: 200))
    }
}
```

Comment: nice way, that you used `Rectangle()` we can use also `Capsule().fill(Color.red).frame(height: 5)`

Answer (score 2):

### Version 1.0.0

I decided to give my answer which is same like **[aheze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66976276/14998134)** answer with this difference that you can have **CustomVerticalAlignment** as well! As I see in your Image in question you want that also:

---

**with CustomVerticalAlignment:** *In center!*
[image]

**without CustomVerticalAlignment:** *off center!*

[image]

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack(alignment: .customVerticalAlignment) {
            
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "star")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                    .padding()
                    .border(Color.black, width: 5)
                    .alignmentGuide(.customVerticalAlignment) { d in d[VerticalAlignment.center] }
                
                Text("Text")
            }
            
            Capsule()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(height: 5)
                .alignmentGuide(.customVerticalAlignment) { d in d[VerticalAlignment.center] }
            
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "star")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                    .padding()
                    .border(Color.black, width: 5)
                    .alignmentGuide(.customVerticalAlignment) { d in d[VerticalAlignment.center] }
                
                Text("Text")
            }
            
            Capsule()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(height: 5)
                .alignmentGuide(.customVerticalAlignment) { d in d[VerticalAlignment.center] }
            
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "star")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                    .padding()
                    .border(Color.black, width: 5)
                    .alignmentGuide(.customVerticalAlignment) { d in d[VerticalAlignment.center] }
                
                Text("Text")
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


extension VerticalAlignment {
    
    struct CustomVerticalAlignment: AlignmentID {
        
        static func defaultValue(in d: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            d[VerticalAlignment.center]
        }
        
    }
    
    static let customVerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment(CustomVerticalAlignment.self)
    
}
```

---

### Update Version 2.0.0

About this version: I would say it does the same job of version 1.0.0 in less code and also Text and Line are not depending on VStack or eachother any moere!

---

[image]

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack {
            
            image.overlay(text.offset(y: 40), alignment: .bottom)
            
            capsule
            
            image.overlay(text.offset(y: 40), alignment: .bottom)
            
            capsule
            
            image.overlay(text.offset(y: 40), alignment: .bottom)
            
        }
        .padding(50)
    }

    var image: some View {
        
        return Image(systemName: "star.fill")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .padding(10)
            .shadow(radius: 10)
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .border(Color.black, width: 5)
        
    }
    
    var capsule: some View {
        
        return Capsule()
            .fill(Color.red)
            .frame(height: 5)
        
    }
    
    var text: some View {
        
        return Text("Hello World!")
            .lineLimit(1)
            .fixedSize()
        
    }
    
}
```

---

Comment: Nice! I didn't even know `customVerticalAlignment` existed.

Comment: We can even make and use `customHorizontalAlignment` if we needed, in that case that would get applied to VStack .

Comment: Hey, this is closest to the solution to what I needed, thanks! But there's a one detail that's important to me. The line and text shouldn't influence each other when HStack is positioning the views, if you notice in my picture the text may go beyond the starting point of the line at the left most VStack, I hope that makes sense and thank you again.

Comment: I think I got what you mean, I will update my code for you soon!

Comment: Sure! My english is quite bad and sorry I can't explain more clearly. 

https://i.ibb.co/qpTsC5g/image.png, I did this now by setting the VStacks to fixed width and setting Text to be fixedSize() but now the text goes out of screen.

Comment: I think that is about your wrong code placement and it is not issue about the Answer, but let me update the Answer for you, then you try again

Comment: Yeah yeah, I know that, I am just showing how it should be and that I am trying things out! Thanks again btw.

Comment: @BeginnerSirius: see the Version 2.0.0, I think it solve all issues

Answer (score 1):

You could define a `Shape` that represents your line.

I used the `spacing` parameter of `HStack` to do the spacing:

```
struct MyLine : Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.midY))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.midY))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 10) {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "pencil")
                Text("Label")
            }
            MyLine().stroke(Color.red)
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "pencil")
                Text("Label 2")
            }
            MyLine().stroke(Color.red)
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "pencil")
                Text("Label 3")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could add a `lineWidth` parameter to make the `stroke` thicker:

```
.stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 4)
```

Also, if you didn't using `spacing` on the `HStack`, you could using a `padding` modifier on either the `VStack`s or the `MyLine`s to get the spacing.

Comment: It is working way, but do not think you it is overkill for simple line draw?

Comment: How is it overkill?

Comment: we could just use Color or Rectangle or Capsule, why we need use Shape here?

Comment: It gives plenty of flexibility. First of all, it allows you to define the line semantically in the code, which can really help for legibility. Secondly, one could use `StrokeStyle` to get even more precise about the rendering. Of course, as with many things, there are multiple possibilities -- `Color` or `Rectangle` would work, too. You're welcome to add answers with those. I don't think there's anything "overkill" about it.